# Extract failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid container object in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I added all the jar in `lib` and `lib/ext`, but still getting error in Jmeter tool

My Config is Jmeter 2.9 and java 7.

error is

> com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor: Extract failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid container object

Comment: you need to provide way more information as full error stacktrace, which jar, why not use latest jmeter 3.3...

Comment: i have older script. that is unable to open in newer version. so i am using 2.9

Comment: there's an open thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/up9usJ5I5yQ

Comment: yes, but in that solution was not available

Comment: not enough information to say anything: what's the json path? what's the JSON you are trying to parse? does another JSON path work, or any even simple one fail?